# unknown column '' user@gmail.com" in the field?

Tags: php, database

> I'm making network admin panel for my website. For this, I've created
>   a normal pin generator for every user (just a requirement on my
>   website). So, in my pin-request database in phpmyadmin, I've created 4
>   fields, "id, email, amount, date". For email, I'm assgining
>   `$_SESSION['userid']` to "email", and then suppose to pass it to the
>   `$email= $_SESSION['userid'];`   But it is showing me error
>
> ```
> "Unknown user 'user@gmail.com in the field set'"
> ```
>
> I'm getting it why this error is happening as I already given the
>   email field in the database?

```
    <?php
require ('php-includes/connect.php');
include ('php-includes/check-login.php');
   $email= $_SESSION['userid'];
?>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['pin_request'])){

        $amount=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['amount']);
        $date=date("y-m-d");

        //$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['email']);

   //Pin request insert into database
   if($amount!='')
   {

    $query=mysqli_query($con,"insert into pin_request(`email`,`amount`,`date`) values(`$email`,`$amount`,`$date`)");

    if($query)
    {
         echo '<script>alert("Pin Request sent succesfully");window.location.assign("pin-request.php")</script>';
    }
    else{
        echo mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I have attached a link of photo with code

Comment: There is no link!!

Comment: No you have not. And it would be great if you could provide real code. A photo is not very good.

Comment: sorry, code is present now. This is my first time here at stackoverflow.

Comment: still no code ...

Answer (score 0):

try this you have missed the quotes

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO pin_request(email,amount,date) values('".$email."','".$amount."','".$date."')");
```

Comment: Now, I'm getting this error  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''email','amount','date') values('user@gmail.com','1200','17-06-22')' at line 1"

Comment: Added. Now can you help me?

Comment: yup. This what I get--> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''email','amount','date') values(user@gmail.com,1222,17-06-22)' at line 1"